# Javascript library to emulate chrome's device change

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design, desktop

I need to implement a functionality that closely emulates Chrome's device change functionality, that enables the user to see our website under different devices. I could implement it manually, but I'm pretty sure that this is a kinda common problem and there probably is a library that does it.

If not, can anyone point out how does Chrome implements it? Thanks!

P.S. Obviously, the solution should work on other browsers too, as many as possible. I only mention it because I mentioned Chrome several times and a confusion that I'm trying to implement Chrome-specific app might arise ;)

Comment: have you ever tried the reactive device toolbar of chrome? http://prntscr.com/e31pf7 If I've got your question, you likely want to see the behavior of your website in several devices running chrome with different resolutions. If you need to implement it manually, you may want to set the user agent of an iframe manually.

Answer (score 0):

Found https://github.com/nerijusgood/viewport-resizer. I haven't checked it into detail yet, but on the surface it looks like it would do the job. Sharing it as it could be of use to someone else in the future :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to do what I need, it simply shrinks the viewport which does not "activate" the mobile-friendly version of the page like the chrome toolbar does.